# Copying a variable range based on nonempty text fields

Tags: excel, vba, range, conditional-statements, copying

In worksheet1 ('add') I have a table ranging from `A4` to `Z14`. It is used to show a voyage of a ship with the different ports and automatically calculates times and dates. I want to copy this table (this specific voyage) to another worksheet2 ('schedule') with the full itinerary of the vessel. To do this I copy the range to the clipboard using VBA. (I run some other macros with it but explaining becomes somewhat elaborate.)

My problem: I want to copy only the range that contains portcalls. Ports are entered in column C so range `C4` to `C14`. So if there are only three ports in the voyage, `C4` to `C6` contains port names and `C7` to `C14` are empty or 0. The copied range should then be `A4:Z6`. If there are five ports the range should be `A4:Z8`.

Since for some cells the formulas need to be copied, and for some only the values (that come from a general input sheet), I first inserted the complete range and then copied/pasted values of the ranges over it to break the link with the general input sheet.

```
Dim myC As Range
Set myC = ActiveCell
Application.CutCopyMode = False
          'insert 
Sheets("Add").Select
Rows("5:14").Select
Selection.COPY
Sheets("Schedule").Select
myC.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Application.CutCopyMode = False

'paste values voy#/ports            
Sheets("Add").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("B5:C14").Select
Selection.COPY
Sheets("Schedule").Select
myC.Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

--> repeats pastevalues for ranges `E5:J14`, `M5:R14`, `T5:T14`, `AB5:AG14`

the row number of the ranges should depend on the last row with a value in it within the range `C4:C14`

I have looked at many of the different problems/answers but all are slightly different than mine.

Comment: Please share the code you have worked on so far.

Comment: please find code in amended question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to change where it is being pasted in the Schedule sheet as I do not know where ActiveCell is... but this should do the job.

```
Dim lngRowSearch As Long
lngRowSearch = 3
With Sheets("Add")
    Do
        lngRowSearch = lngRowSearch + 1
    Loop Until .Cells(lngRowSearch + 1, 3) = 0
    .Range("A4:Z" & lngRowSearch).Copy
End With
Sheets("Schedule").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Great! thanks a lot! I managed to fit it in without too many trouble and it works as I hoped.